# Getting warning message box while exporting JSON array to excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, excel

I am trying to export JSON array data to Excel.

Here is sample of Json array data

```
jsonResult.Products[{PRODUCT_ID: 123, PRODUCT_NUMBER: "00022", PRODUCT_NAME: "HONDA", PRODUCT_TYPE: "VEHICLE "},
{PRODUCT_ID: 783, PRODUCT_NUMBER: "08412394", PRODUCT_NAME: "HONDA", PRODUCT_TYPE: "MOTOR "}......]
```

Everything is fine and able to see data but I am receiving  a popup message while opening file and when clicked "Yes" able to see correct data in Excel.Ho to avoid showing popup.
[image]

Here is code snippet used to export to Excel.

```
function Export2Excel(data) {
        var excelData = [];
        var colStr = '';
        $("#ddlSelectedlist > option").each(function () {

            colStr += '"' + this.value + '",';
        });

        excelData.push(colStr);

        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
            var item = data[i];
            var cellVal = '';
            var headerString = colStr.substring(0, colStr.length - 1);
            result = headerString
                .split(',')
                .map(key => {
                    var val = item[key.toUpperCase()
                        .replace(/"/g, '')];

                        cellVal += '"' + val + '"\t';
                    }
                    return cellVal;
                })

            excelData.push(cellVal);
        }

        var fileName = 'Test.xlsx';
        var xlData = excelData.join("\n");
        if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) {

            blob = new Blob([xlData], {
                "type": "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf8;"

            });
            if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
            }
        }
        else {
             var blob = new Blob([xlData],
                 { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf8;' });

            var excelUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", excelUrl);
            link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
            link.setAttribute("target", '_blank');
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            if (link.click !== undefined)
                link.click();
            else if (document.createEvent) {
                var eventObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                eventObj.initEvent('click', true, true);
                link.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
            }
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }

    }
```

Please let me know how can i resolve the issue and download file with out warning popup.

Comment: If you want to avoid the pop-up  you need to send an actual Excel file, not content which does not match the content-type header.  Read up on "Office extension hardening"

Comment: @TimWilliams .Thanks for suggestion.I dont want customers change registry keys.Is there anything that can be done at JavaScript level to open downloaded Excel file with out warning.